# Why is this code for multiple histograms on axes not working?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am getting errors for this code when running it on the 'tips' dataset but I can run it on the tulips dataset using a 2 rows and 2 column grid for the 4 variables there. I wonder why I am getting 'too many indices'. The code is also available at [python-graph-gallery](https://python-graph-gallery.com/25-histogram-with-several-variables-seaborn/)from where I obtained it. Am I missing something?

[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrNY8.png)

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `axes` is a one-dimensional array. Try:

```
sns.distplot(df["total_bill"], color="skyblue", ax=axes[0])
sns.distplot(df["tip"], color="olive", ax=axes[1])
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and I figured this out as well after asking this..i just need to give the element index for the 1-D array